# Item highlight for only items with child items

Tags: python, selection, maya

I am trying to create 2 buttons, *prev* and *next*, but instead of selecting the item before or after it in the Maya outliner, I want to select the next or previous item which has children.

To make this clearer: In the image below, if I have selected `grpA_ctrl02`, while executing these 2 buttons it will either select `grpA_ctrl01` or `grpA_ctrl03`, since both of these have child items

How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Another question closed as unclear by users unfamiliar with Maya...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `pickWalk` command.

```
while True:
    cmds.pickWalk(d='left')
    children = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(sl=True), children=True, typ='transform')
    if children:
        break
```

All of this is inside a `while True`, to keep it looping until it finds a valid node.

- First, it walks one node to the left.
- Then it lists child transforms
- If there are children, it matches the requirement, so break
- Otherwise, do all this again, walking one further to the left

For the other direction, do the same thing but with `pickWalk(d='right')`

**Documentation:**
[pickWalk](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/pickWalk.html)
[listRelatives](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/listRelatives.html)

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I realized that it works if the selection is within the same 'level'. If say, my selection is inside of grpA, it will highlights between grpA_ctrl01 and grpA_ctrl03, but it will not highlights grpA (despite it having child transform) nor will it jumps and highlights to the next group of hierarchy outside of grpA. I tried changing the flags in `listRelatives` such as putting in the parent flags etc.. it is not working, or perhaps do I need to define in some manner that `children` plus `parent selection` etc?

Comment: Woah, yeah that would be totally different. Not sure exactly how I'd do that in the same function, but I also can't fathom why I'd want to. It seems that functionality might be better suited to a different button, and a new stack overflow question if you get stuck implementing it. Good luck!

Comment: Sure, thanks alot! Probably I will try playing around and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Comment: One pointer: walk up, then left, then down. Three separate walks